# Can Entity Framework be used with any ADO.NET provider?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

My company is using ADO.NET data readers to read from a non-standard database.

The vendor ships with the database a single DLL, with the `DbDataReader`, `DbDataAdapter` classes (targeting .NET Framework V2).

I am contemplating moving to Entity Framework, but all the tutorials I read mention some sort of Visual Studio add-in or NuGet package, to be able to connect to the DB from Server Explorer, etc.

Hence the question: **Can any ADO.NET DLL be used to get the full Entity Framework experience, or do I have to wait until the vendor ships a specific tool?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite of the fact that EntityFrameworks uses ADO.NET on low level, there are no 'generic' EF Provider that can work with any 'abstract' ADO.NET provider. For popular databases like SQL Server, MySql, PostgreSql EF Provider implementations are provided by MS or open-source community; in all other cases [you need to implement EF provider by yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/writing-an-ef-data-provider).

But, in most cases, it is possible to use alternative data layers that can use any ADO.NET provider implementation without need to write any additional code. In particular, you can check my library [NReco.Data](https://github.com/nreco/data) which provides SQL-generation capabilities and can map query results to POCO models like EF (data annotations are supported!).